# How to reduce size of MainActivity/outsource UI code

Tags: java, android

most of my apps are apps with just one screen (due to the functionality) sometimes being extended by "floating" popups that are basically RelativeLayouts (containing other UI elements) that are being added to the Main layout, keeping the UI Elements of the Main layout active and "touchable" in the background.

For a better understanding, please just look at the sketch (purely symbolic):
[image]

If you include all the stuff from the popups as well, I have about 90 UI elements, a dozen of custom View classes like buttons, sliders, ... at a time, all of them needing to have certain listeners running on them, all of them having to be resized on start up [...]

I, in fact, write quite efficient (in terms of amount of bytes used) code, and if there is a 3-line method to return a value that replaces 4 lines of additional code, I write this method just to satisfy myself. However, I quite don't understand how to outsource code from my MainActivity to other classes. Of course, if there is a calculation to be made, this is something that I put into another class rather than just creating a method in my MainActivity class. Anyway, my MainActivity is now at **1600 lines of code** which is an awful amount of text to overview for debugging, adding or changing code. The variable declarations of my UI elements alone take 100 lines of code (maybe 70 lines if compressed)

That was the longest explanation I ever made for a post but now we get to my question:

How can/do you outsource code like listeners, UI stuff like findViewById() or similar things to other classes? Are there common practices to do so in an efficient way? I don't want to go for clumsy workarounds that skyrocket the CPU, so "smooth" stuff is stuff I am looking for.

It might be KIND OF off-topic but I hope it's ok to be asked here.

Comment: Are you not using resource xml files to build your UI? Each bit of new functionality (even in the same view) could be put into fragments

Comment: I build like 80% of the UI from within the XML, but there are things that depend on screen size or device-specific differences which can't be read from within the XML. Thanks for the hint regarding the fragments, I will see if it is something I can make use of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is particular answer on your question because I suppose it's all about experience which you can get reading source code of other projects for instance. But I have few advices which could help you:

**1.** Use libraries which eliminate boilerplate code like `findViewById` and listeners. One of them is [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

7 lines of code:

```
View text = findViewById(R.id.text_id);
text.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                //
            }
        }
);
```

2 lines code:

```
@OnClick(R.id.text_id) public void handleClickOnText() {
    //
}
```

**2.** Use static helper classes:

4 lines of code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage(R.string.new_message);
builder.setTitle(R.string.create_calendar_title);
builder.show();
```

1 line of code:

```
DialogsHelper.newMessage(this);
```

**3.** Read about `MVP`. It's about modular app architecture. Roughly speaking it helps to divide raw `View` from logic.

Basic sample:

```
public static class SomePresenter {

    private SomeView view;

    public SomePresenter(SomeView view) {
        this.view = view;
        view.showProgressLoading();
        loadData();
    }

    private void loadData(){
        //loading data from some server
    }

    private void loadingDataHandler(SomeModel model){
        view.showData(model);
    }
}

public static class SomeView extends View{

    @Inject(R.id.text_progress_title) TextView text;

    public SomeView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
    }

    public void showData(SomeModel model){
        text.setText(model.dataA + ":" +  model.dataB);
    }

    public void showProgressLoading(){
        text.setText(R.string.progress);
    }
}

public static class SomeModel{
    public final int dataA;
    public final int dataB;
}
```

And your `onCreate` method of activity could look like this:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);

    new SomePresenter(someView);
}
```

Comment: These are pretty cool things to learn more about, thanks dude!